# Zend Form Decorators Error in Table

Tags: php, zend-framework, html-table, zend-form

I am using the next decorators for my input. I want to make this as table.

```
$this->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors',
           array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
           array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
           array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
   ));
```

But after form validation Errors showing not in td. How can I do this?
I want to make the next makeup:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Lable</td>
      <td>Input</td>
      <td>Error</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->setDecorators(
   array(
      'ViewHelper',
      array(
         array(
            'data'=>'HtmlTag'
         ),
         array(
            'tag' => 'td'
         )
      ),
      array(
         'Label', 
         array(
            'tag' => 'td'
         )
      ),
      array(
         'Errors', 
         array(
            'tag' => 'td'
         )
      ),
      array(
         array(
            'row'=>'HtmlTag'
         ),
         array(
            'tag'=>'tr'
         )
      )
   )
);
```